# can not decralation place holder view

Tags: android, gradle

i had a problem in my gradelle with response Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.7.1.

i try like

a. settings > build exception deployment > gradle > uncheck offline work it's failed
b. clean and reburd it's failed
c. invalidate and restart failed

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "sid.len.mobile"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // picks the JavaMail license file
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
    }

 repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
    url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
      }
      }

      dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.0.1'

compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.4.0@aar'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'

//noinspection OutdatedLibrary
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

compile files('libs/jtds-1.3.1.jar')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.7.1'
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add this repository:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

while that `build.gradle` seems to have more than one problem, including duplicate `*.jar` references and a few outdated libraries (in case you may wonder why it still won't build).

at least use `buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"`.